# Cut off add tag button On new redesign too

Tags: bug, design, homepage

I have noticed on the homepage of stackoverflow the add tags button is always cut off. I am using On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and this is on Google Chrome 24.

[image: Cut off image]

Comment: Hm, is that default zoom? Looks fine to me on win chrome 24

Comment: @BenBrocka yes this is the default zoom, actually when i increase the zoom level to 110% it looks fine